# Null values of object from post method in thymealf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hello i trying create updatable from in Thymealf, i pass object to the model by get method and i trying change some values and call post method when i call it i get a null values of object. Maybe example it's clear it up.

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editUsers(Model model){
 //  Call new userDTO constructor and assign values
UserDTO userData =...

    model.addAttribute("userData", userData);
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/edit/editUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editAllProfile(  Model model, @ModelAttribute("userData") UserDTO userDTO) {

}
```

In post method userDTO.name etc is null

view

```
 <form  id="editUserForm"  th:action="@{/user/edit/editUser}" th:object="${userData}" th:method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <a class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('editUserForm').submit();"><img th:src="@{../../img/save.jpg}"/> Save all</a>
<form>
```

In browser name is have some value, but when i click Save button i have only nulls

Comment: can you also show your UserDTO

Comment: Even `name` field is null? Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29885846/5684265) answer is relevant to your question.