# Springs form null values

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have a small problem with my form in spring, it is a simple form with title, username and password, validation works as if I try to submit an empty form I get an error however if I input values in and submit the form, it is submitted but it displays that values inserted are "null".

Domain:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=6)
    private String password;

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }

    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

    public List<Note> getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    @OneToMany
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/create/user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
    <p>Title: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></p>
    <p>Username: <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<div class="form-group">
    <ol class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" th:each="user : ${user}">
            <a href="#" th:href="@{/note/}+${user.id}"><span th:text=" ${user.title} + ${user.username} + ${user.password} "></span></a>
            <a href="#" th:href="@{/delete/user/}+${user.id}" class="pull-right">delete</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    protected UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUser(Model model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
            model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
            model.addAttribute("type", "danger");
            model.addAttribute("message", "Please fill in all the fields" +
                    "Username needs to be at least 2 characters" +
                    "Passwords needs to contain at least 6 characters");
            return "user";
        }

        userService.save(user);

        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("cards", userService.findAll());

        model.addAttribute("type", "success");
        model.addAttribute("message", "A new user has been added");

        return "user";
    }
```

[image]

If any additional code in needed please let me know, I am still newbie in Spring

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your project? I could try to see it. I'm not very familiar with this theme but I would like to try

Comment: Also it could be a duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885802/form-parameter-is-null-with-thymeleaf-and-spring-mvc

Comment: I am working on it locally so I cannot really show it to you, unless I send it to you? That solution doesn't work for me

Comment: What do you mean? Are inserted values `null` in database, or your form displays empty fields?

Comment: I have included a screenshot. Basically I type the values in, add it and record is added but as null null null instead of the actual values

Comment: @Przemek Wojtas Please, see the link below. ahttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669212/send-datas-from-html-to-controller-in-thymeleaf If I am not mistaking you initialize your pojo and expect to get it in the same method.

Comment: Found error was <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" th:each="user : ${user}"> and should be <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" th:each="user : ${users}">

Comment: @Przemek Wojtas Create an answer. My congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Found an error by reviewing the code:

In the form when outputting registered users it was:

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" th:each="user : ${user}">
```

While it should be:

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" th:each="user : ${users}">
```